# Read and Edit Large Text Files in Azure Datalake

Tags: azure, text-editor

Is there any online tool that we can use to view/edit text files in Azure cloud directly without downloading to local machine and use text editor like UltraEdit or EMeditor?

thanks
Anbu

Answer (score 0):

Yes; there is an excellent web interface for Kudu, the git deployment engine for Azure. The documentation is here: ["Accessing the kudu service"](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service). In short, the URL address for the web interface is `https://[site-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/`.